# How do i mount root files from recovery mode

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, dedicated-server

Hey can anyone tell how to mount my root files to edit  sshd_config in recovery mode? im new to linux so can you give me step by step instructions?
im using ubuntu as recovery mode. to edit files in centos.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:
if the rescue mode mounted your filesystem for you then just edit the sshd_config and reboot, if it did not mount it for you then best guess not knowing your server specifics would be:

mkdir /mnt/sos

mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sos

nano /mnt/sos/etc/ssh/sshd_config

that assumes your sda1 is your / if you made a separate partition for /boot then it is probably sda2 you need to mount.